# How to query Azure Master DB from a Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to run this query from an instance on premise to the Master database in Azure.

I can query the other database on the Azure instance with my linked server so that is working and the query I'm trying to run, runs when I log onto the Azure instance.

I just cannot get it to run from my server that has a linked server object set up for Azure.

The code I have tried is:

```
SELECT [database_id],[name],[Compatibility_level],[collation_name],[state_desc]
,[recovery_model_Desc],[is_broker_enabled],[is_cdc_enabled]
FROM [LinkedServerName].[Master].[sys].[databases]
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
EXEC ( 'SELECT [database_id],[name],[Compatibility_level],[collation_name],[state_desc] ,[recovery_model_Desc],[is_broker_enabled],[is_cdc_enabled]
    FROM [Master].[sys].[databases]') AT [LinkedServerName]
```

Again with no success. I am getting this error:

Msg 40515, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
Reference to database and/or server name in 'Master.sys.sp_tables_info_90_rowset_64' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Any ideas to help me get around this?

Comment: I guess while creating your `linked server` you had mentioned the `catalog` or the `Azure SQL database` for which you want to create a linked server to an Azure SQL database which certainly is not `master` database. More importantly `Azure` does not allow to alter the master database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the linked server you specified the user database as the “[Catalog](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0016.htm)” database, you did not specified the master database as the catalog (the database used for the linked server). That is the reason you are using cross database queries, and cross database queries using three and four-part names are not supported on Azure SQL Database as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information#transact-sql-syntax-not-supported-in-azure-sql-database).

Additionally not all sys tables are supported on Azure SQL Database. You will find some DMVs available on Azure SQL Database that do not exist on SQL Server on-premises and vice versa.

Comment: That has fixed part one, thank you. The next issue after that is then querying the user databases within Azure. Will I need to separate Linked Servers to Azure one looking at Master the other at DatabaseA?

Comment: Yes, please. Create another linked server. Creating External Data Sources may help on some scenarios. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/